# Remove / Delete Legend in PyQtGraph

Tags: python, pyqt5, data-visualization, pyqtgraph

Two lines are created on the live chart and a legend is added. At the next update, the lines on the chart are deleted using self.pw.clear().

But the legend is not deleted, and with each update, a new instance of the legend is added, there are a lot of them and the FPS of the schedule update quickly drops.

Here http://www.pyqtgraph.org/documentation/graphicsItems/plotitem.html says Clear(): “Remove all items from the ViewBox.”

Attempting to Clear / removeItem - have not yet helped (either the syntax is incorrect, or the procedure call is incorrect).

**How to delete a legend when updating a chart or stop multiple legends creation?**

```
import random
from PyQt5 import QtGui
import pyqtgraph as pg
import sys

class Mainwindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(Mainwindow, self).__init__()
        self.centralWidget = QtGui.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)
        self.resize(1000, 500)

        self.vbox = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        self.pw = pg.PlotWidget()
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.pw)
        self.centralWidget.setLayout(self.vbox)

        # Update chart
        self.timer = pg.QtCore.QTimer()
        self.timer.setSingleShot(False)
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.update)
        self.timer.start(10)

    def update(self):
        x = []
        y = []
        z = []
        for i in range(10000):
            x.append(i)
            y.append(random.uniform(0, 1))
            z.append(1 + random.uniform(0, 1))

        self.pw.clear()
        line_red = pg.PlotCurveItem(x, y, clear=True, pen='r', name='Red')
        line_yellow = pg.PlotCurveItem(x, z, clear=True, pen='y', name='Yellow')
        self.pw.addItem(line_red)
        self.pw.addItem(line_yellow)
        self.pw.addLegend()

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
ex = Mainwindow(app)
ex.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sub>You have an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), instead of asking How to update the plot? questions How to eliminate the duplicate legend ?. So I will point out a solution to the underlying problem.</sub>

Considering the above, the logic is to only create the items once and update the information using the `setData()` method.

```py
import random
import sys

import pyqtgraph as pg
from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtGui


class Mainwindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(Mainwindow, self).__init__()
        self.centralWidget = QtGui.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)
        self.resize(1000, 500)

        vbox = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self.centralWidget)
        self.pw = pg.PlotWidget()
        self.pw.addLegend()
        vbox.addWidget(self.pw)

        # Update chart
        self.timer = pg.QtCore.QTimer()
        self.timer.setSingleShot(False)
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.update)
        self.timer.start(10)

        self.line_red = pg.PlotCurveItem(clear=True, pen="r", name="Red")
        self.line_yellow = pg.PlotCurveItem(clear=True, pen="y", name="Yellow")

        self.pw.addItem(self.line_red)
        self.pw.addItem(self.line_yellow)

    def update(self):
        x = []
        y = []
        z = []
        for i in range(10000):
            x.append(i)
            y.append(random.uniform(0, 1))
            z.append(1 + random.uniform(0, 1))
        self.line_red.setData(x, y)
        self.line_yellow.setData(x, z)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Mainwindow(app)
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Yes, now I see my mistake. Your code is working correctly. Also, thanks to your decision with setData(), I also compared the performance of your code and mine (both without a legend) - your code added +14..19% to the FPS. Cool!